# two iframe's in one page, the 2nd iframe to auto height

Tags: html, iframe, height, scrollbar

I am trying to achieve auto resizing of the 2nd iframe in this code,

Any help would be appreciated.

**CSS**

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: static;
    border-collapse: collapse
}
iframe {
    width: 100%
}
.header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000
}
.content {
    height: 100%
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="header"><div><h1>Header</h1></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="content"><iframe name="iFrame1" height="85" src="Materials AU Stocked Header.htm" scrolling="no" frameborder="1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="content"><iframe name="iFrame2" height="100%" src="Materials AU Stocked.htm" scrolling="yes" frameborder="1"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If it is possible please don't use Frames!

Comment: You should not be using table to do layout.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is possible, the two files are generated out of Business Objects and i need to merge the two of them to diplay on one page.  all opened locally from a file, no webserver used.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the height or your iframes? Do you want the second iframe to go all the way down to the bottom of the page an no more? But start under the first iframe? You want it to fill the rest of the page?

Comment: Hi 3dgoo, correct, that sounds excatly what i am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `position: absolute` with your second iframe and specifying `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right`.

This requires your `#header` and first `iframe` have a fixed height.

Note I've put in some external websites in the iframe `src` for testing purposes. Replace these with your desired html pages.

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<iframe id="iFrame1" name="iFrame1" src="http://yahoo.com"></iframe>
<div id="iFrame2Container">
    <iframe id="iFrame2" name="iFrame2" src="http://yahoo.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden
}
#header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    height: 19px;
}

#iFrame1 {
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#iFrame2Container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
#iFrame2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kfHz4/)**

A few extra things that I noticed in your code

- You shouldn't use tables for layout
- You shouldn't put spaces in your html filename

  - Rename `Materials AU Stocked Header.htm` to somethin like `Materials-AU-Stocked Header.htm`
- Close tags you open

  - `<iframe>` needs `</iframe>` after it